# How do you use hist to plot relative frequencies in R?

Tags: r, histogram

How do you use hist() to plot relative frequencies in R?

If I do the following, I will get a density plot, but I want a relative frequency plot:

```
a <- c(0,0,0,1,1,2)
hist(a, freq=FALSE)
```

I want to see a histogram with the following relative frequencies:

.5 for 0 to 1,

.33 for 1 to 2,

and .166 for 2 to 3.

Comment: apparently you can't use freq=TRUE with plot=FALSE, so this is a good question with some good answers below, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use hist() function in R to get percentages as opposed to raw frequencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324683/use-hist-function-in-r-to-get-percentages-as-opposed-to-raw-frequencies)

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer in ggplot : [Relative frequency histogram in R, ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430885/relative-frequency-histogram-in-r-ggplot)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can try using the `histogram()` function in lattice

```
a <- c(0,0,0,1,1,2)
library(lattice)
histogram(a)
```

defaults to percent.

Comment: What a pity that it uses such an ugly color as default :)

Answer (score 9):

I've added a new function to the [HistogramTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistogramTools/) package on CRAN, `PlotRelativeFrequency()` which takes a histogram object and generates a relative frequency histogram plot.  This is available now from R-Forge and will be in HistogramTools 0.3 for the next [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) release.

Basically, you just need to make two modifications to the default histograms in R.  First, you need to divide each count by the sum of all of the counts, and you need to replace the y-axis label to note that it is now plotting Relative Frequencies.

```
x<-runif(100)
h<-hist(x, plot=F)
h$counts <- h$counts / sum(h$counts)
plot(h, freq=TRUE, ylab="Relative Frequency")
```

Or, simply

```
install.packages("HistogramTools", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library(HistogramTools)
PlotRelativeFrequency(hist(x, plot=F))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
hist(a, breaks=c(0, 1, 2, 3), freq=FALSE, right=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not properly a traditional histogram...

```
h<-hist(yourdata)
plot(h$mids,100*h$counts/sum(h$counts),type="h")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
histo<-hist(yourvariable)
barplot(histo$counts/n,col="white",space=0)->bp   # n=length(yourvariable)
axis(1,at=c(bp),labels=histo$mids)
title(ylab="Relative Frequency",xlab="Your Variable Name")
```