# how to rescale the Y axis (frequency) of a histogram in R?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have this [raster file](https://echange-fichiers.inra.fr/get?k=aG724N9pJ0Fcv8Pe03i)
 and I want to rescale the y axis (frequency) to [0,1](by dividing the frequency by the sum of all frequencies).

```
conne <- file("C:\\fined.bin","rb")
sd<- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
y<-t(matrix((data=sd), ncol=1440, nrow=720))
r = raster(y)
hist(r, breaks=30, main="SMD_2010",
        xlab="Pearson correlation", ylab="Frequency", xlim=c(-1,1))

example:


        values  frequency        (rescaled by dividing each frequency by the sum(85600))
          -1    0                       0
        -0.5    100               0.001168224
           0    38000                 0.443925234
         0.5    7500                  0.087616822
        0.75    40000                 0.46728972
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps use `density( )` around your data.

Comment: Use: hist(..., probability = TRUE)

Comment: ok, then maybe something like: hist_temp <- hist(...);
plot(hist_temp$counts/sum(hist_temp$counts), type = "s")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to save the histogram os object. If you look on structure of this object you can see that heights of histogram bars are stored in element `counts`.

```
r<-sample(1:25000,1000)
hist.ob <- hist(r)
str(hist.ob)
List of 7
 $ breaks     : num [1:14] 0 2000 4000 6000 8000 10000 12000 14000 16000 18000 ...
 $ counts     : int [1:13] 75 46 72 91 71 91 74 87 86 82 ...
 $ intensities: num [1:13] 3.75e-05 2.30e-05 3.60e-05 4.55e-05 3.55e-05 4.55e-05 3.70e-05 4.35e-05 4.30e-05 4.10e-05 ...
 $ density    : num [1:13] 3.75e-05 2.30e-05 3.60e-05 4.55e-05 3.55e-05 4.55e-05 3.70e-05 4.35e-05 4.30e-05 4.10e-05 ...
 $ mids       : num [1:13] 1000 3000 5000 7000 9000 11000 13000 15000 17000 19000 ...
 $ xname      : chr "r"
 $ equidist   : logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

To transform your data so that sum of all bar heights will be 1, you have to divide the each number with the sum of `counts` number. Then use `plot()` function to get the new plot.

```
hist.ob$counts<-hist.ob$counts/sum(hist.ob$counts)
plot(hist.ob)
```

Comment: @Barry Dividing by sum() will change the range. So the dividing by maximal value will keep range 0-1. If this not the solution you need then please update your question to explain more what you mean by scale y axis.

Comment: @Barry - checked with your sample data - if you use sum(hist.ob$counts), then the total sum of heights will be 1. In my sample data all values were quite similar so you saw so small values after transformation.

Comment: Here's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324683/use-hist-function-in-r-to-get-percentages-as-opposed-to-raw-frequencies) that retains the y-axis.