# How to plot a density curve in R using percentages?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, percentage, density-plot

I'm not sure if what I'm asking is conceptually correct, mainly because the definition of density itself, but anyway...

I'm trying to plot a density graph in R, but using percentages in the y axis. In the following image, I succeed plotting the curves that I need, but it doesn't seem to me that is the percentages what is in the y axis.

[image]

The code I use to make it is following:

```
ggplot(data = base_15
           , aes(x = inv_hab, y = ..count../sum(..count..)
           , colour = abrg_natjur)
           ) + geom_density()
```

I've already searched in a lot of places, like:

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_(ggplot2)/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation

[Use hist() function in R to get percentages as opposed to raw frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324683/use-hist-function-in-r-to-get-percentages-as-opposed-to-raw-frequencies)

But I'm still failing. When I use

```
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)))
```

it works, the y axis changes to percentages, but it doesn't work for geom_density. I would like to plot it with lines, not columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need percentage sign i.e. to use `0.1%` instead of `0.001`, or is the problem that the densities do not add up to 100% or 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `stat` used by a `geom_*` to get the desired output.

I'll use the `mpg` data set from the `ggplot2` package for this example.

As you noted,

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg) + aes(x = hwy, y = ..count../sum(..count..)) + geom_histogram()
```

yields the wanted output as a histogram:
[image]

By calling `geom_density` with the `stat = 'bin'`, the same stat as `geom_histogram`, instead of the default `stat = 'density'` for `geom_density` you'll get what I think you are looking for:

```
ggplot(mpg) + aes(x = hwy, y = ..count../sum(..count..)) + geom_density(stat = 'bin')
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, Peter. That is exaclty what I was looking for! Thank you very much!!