# Simple histogram plot wrong?

Tags: r, histogram

```
test <- rep(5,20)
hist(test,freq=FALSE,breaks=5)
```

The vector contains 20 times the value 5. When I plot this with `freq=FALS`E and `breaks=5` I expect to see 1 bar at x=5 with height = 1.0, because the value 5 makes up 100% of the data.

Why do I instead see 1 bar that ranges from x=0 to x=5 and has height = 0.2 ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hist` plots an estimate of the probability **density** when `freq=FALSE` or `prob=TRUE`, so the total **area** of the bars in the histogram sums to 1.  Since the horizontal range of the single bar that is plotted is (0,5), it follows that the height must be 0.2 (5*0.2=1)

If you *really* want the histogram you were expecting (i.e. heights correspond to fraction of counts, areas don't necessarily sum to 1), you can do this:

```
 h <- hist(test,plot=FALSE)
 h$counts <- h$counts/length(test)
 plot(h)
```

Another possibility is to force the bar widths to be equal to 1.0, e.g.

```
 hist(test,freq=FALSE,breaks=0:10)
```

Or maybe you want

```
 plot(table(test)/length(test))
```

or

```
 plot(table(test)/length(test),lwd=10,lend="butt")
```

?
See also: [How do you use hist to plot relative frequencies in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073223/how-do-you-use-hist-to-plot-relative-frequencies-in-r)

Comment: so how do i get 1 bar at the value 5 of height 1.0 ?

Comment: no I didn't. but now I have tried that and I still get the same result ... ?

Comment: really? are you sure the height isn't now 1.0?

Comment: yes the height is 1.0, but the width of the bar is too large. i have 1 big square which ranges from 0 to 5 on the x-axis. i need 1 bar at the value 5, which indicates that the value 5 makes up 100% of the data.

Comment: you might prefer my second suggestion above.

Comment: @user3182532, if BenBolker's answer addressed correctly your question, you might consider accepting his answer by clicking on the green checkmark under the vote arrows. Tks.