# Relative frequency histogram in R, ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, frequency, lattice

I can draw relative frequency histogram in R, using `lattice` package:

```
a <- runif(100)
library(lattice)
histogram(a)
```

I want to get the same graph in `ggplot`. I tried

```
dt <- data.frame(a)
ggplot(dt, aes(x = a)) + 
geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop..))+
 scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

but it doesn't work like that. What I should change in the code? Calculating relative frequency before graph is not an option for me.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `geom_histogram`

Comment: ggplot(dt, aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram()

Comment: No, i need relative frequency, not a count.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You want a histogram, not a barplot, so:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = a)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))), bins = 8) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

`lattice`:

[image]

`ggplot2`:

[image]

You can see that the binning algorithm works slightly different for the two packages.

Comment: Another option is to use `geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(density)))` directly. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html#computed-variables

Comment: @Kiteration, That gives a different plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=a)) + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), group = 1)
```

Comment: No, with this method i only see three vertical lines, not a distribution.